# Empty claims from JwtBearer middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

Using ASP.NET Core 3.1. I want to validate a JWT (and the roles in it).

**Startup**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton(Configuration);

    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.MetadataAddress = "https://example.com/.well-known/openid-configuration";
        });

    services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, MyRoleHandler>();
}
```

**MyRoleHandler**

```cs
public class MyRoleHandler : IAuthorizationHandler
{
    public Task HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
    {
        var claims = context.User.Claims;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

**https://example.com/.well-known/openid-configuration**

```
{
    "issuer": "https://example.com",
    "jwks_uri": "https://example.com/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks",
    "authorization_endpoint": "https://example.com/connect/authorize",
    "token_endpoint": "https://example.com/connect/token",
    "end_session_endpoint": "https://example.com/connect/endsession",
    "check_session_iframe": "https://example.com/connect/checksession",
    "device_authorization_endpoint": "https://example.com/connect/deviceauthorization",
    "frontchannel_logout_supported": true,
    "frontchannel_logout_session_supported": true,
    "backchannel_logout_supported": true,
    "backchannel_logout_session_supported": true,
    "response_types_supported": ["code", "token", "id_token", "id_token token", "code id_token", "code token", "code id_token token"],
    "subject_types_supported": ["public"],
    "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": ["RS256"],
    "code_challenge_methods_supported": ["plain", "S256"],
    "upgrade_endpoint": "https://example.com/connect/upgrade",
    "end_session_accesstoken_endpoint": "https://example.com/connect/endsession/accesstoken",
    "active_session_endpoint": "https://example.com/connect/activesession"
}
```

`claims` is empty. What am I doing wrong here? I was under the impression the `JwtBearer` middleware will configure itself when given the openid-configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out now that the error was in fact that the TokenValidationParameters must be set correctly. I don't exactly know why, but as soon as I add them in any capacity, the claims are correctly decoded.

So now I added them as follows:

```
services
.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(opts =>
{
    opts.Authority = Env.Get("AUTHORITY_BASE_URL");

    opts.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = Env.Get("ALLOWED_ISSUER"),
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = Env.Get("ALLOWED_AUDIENCE"),
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Env.GetDouble("CLOCK_SKEW")),
        RoleClaimType = "authorities"
    };
});
```

And now, in my MyRoleHandler, the claims are correctly decoded an I can check them.